# Tomcat Restart Virtual Host from Tomcat Web Application Manager

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

I have 3 virtual host run on tomcat

`abc.domain.com
def.domain.com
ghi.domain.com`

When I update one application, I have to restart the tomcat service (I run `./shutdown.sh` and `./startup.sh` script).

When I use Tomcat Web Application Manager, it want to be restated. Event I stop one of application, it still works, when I call it on browser.

On localhost, I used those method (thought Tomcat Web Application Manager) to restart the application and it works (without virtual host).

`localhost:8080/abc
localhost:8080/def
localhost:8080/ghi`

Have someone idea, how to restart a application without restart the tomcat service?
My purpose is I don't want to disturb the other applications.

Thank you

in `server.xml` file

```
<Host name="abc.domain.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="" docBase="/tomcat/webapps/abc"
               debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
      </Host>

<Host name="def.domain.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="" docBase="/tomcat/webapps/def"
               debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>

<Host name="ghi.domain.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="" docBase="/tomcat/webapps/ghi"
               debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
      </Host>`
```

Answer (score 1):

So, somehow I found the solution in the tomcat documentation.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html#server.xml

**Note that the directory structures under the appBase for each host should not overlap each other.**

So, I need to edit the `server.xml` from

```
<Host name="abc.domain.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="" docBase="/tomcat/webapps/abc"
               debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
      </Host>
```

to

```
<Host name="abc.domain.com"  appBase="abc" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="" docBase="xyz"
               debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
      </Host>

<Host name="def.domain.com"  appBase="def"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="" docBase="klm"
               debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

And go to Tomcat Virtual Host Manager to **stop** and **start** virtual host

I hope it can help.